# SSL Certificate for Load Balancer using gcloud

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, load-balancing, gcloud

Question: When I use the UI to add a new SSL certificate to a Target HTTPS Proxy, I am expected to enter Certificate, Private Key and Certificate Chain. In the command line, it only asks for Certificate and Private Key. Am I missing something?

[image][image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A brief summary on certificates

When you sign a *certificate request* (scr) basically you are signing a public key together with some useful information that links that public key to the domain, organisation or entity that should be the unique owner of the private key.

But you need to sign this public key to make sure you can check no one modified it, but which key whould you use to sign it? If you could use the corresponding private key, then everyone would be able to take ownership of every Domain, therefore you need to sign the certificate making use of the private key of a third trusted entity.

Of course you trust this entity thanks to a certificate that has been signed but an other entity and so on till you find a certificate that is [self-signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate).

This is the only way to end end a loop that would be infinite otherwise, this self signed certificate identifies a root certificate authority (CA), you have a list of them in your Browser.

You can as well self-sign your own certificate, but since it will be not in the default list in the browser they will see a warning saying that your website is not trustable.

**Therefore you should provide a certificate, the chain and the private key to protect your traffic and show your identity, therefore why they ask for different information?**

Basically they ask for the same but formatted in different ways:

- For [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl) they ask a "PEM encoded X.509 public key certificate" and the key, from the documentation you can notice that the certificate is  **"your concatenated SSL certificate"** therefore is the whole chain
- With the [gcloud command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/compute/ssl-certificates/create) the certificate and the key is needed, again the certificate is **"The certificate chain must be no greater than 5 certs long. The chain must include at least one intermediate cert."** again is the whole chain.
- From [the console](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/load-balancer-howto) you will need to provide the same information but divided, **your certificate that is the "Public key certificate", then the chain composed buy intermetiate and root and finally the private key**.

However I agree that is misleading and that the same information should be asked always in the same way.

**For example** for google.com the complete chain is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

The first one is the Public key certificate, the second one is the chain since there is not intermediate and it is as well the root certificate.

You can decode the certificate for example [here](https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-decoder.html).

- The first certificate belongs to Google
- The second one to [GeoTrust Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoTrust)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let me try it out and see if appending the chain to my cert would work with gcloud.

Comment: Did you succeed at the end? @AnandSharma

Comment: Sorry, @GalloCedrone. I had gotten a bit distracted since I posted my question. Your suggestion did help. Basically, what I ended up doing was using the following command to create SSL certificate using gcloud:

`gcloud compute ssl-certificates create demo-ssl-cert --certificate fullchain1.pem --private-key privkey1.pem`